# С# как пропустить текстовый файл, если он был удален или изменен

Tags: c#

C# у меня есть метод который читает из 2 двух файлов вопросы и ответы.

Возникла вот такая проблема, если файл переименовать или удалить, программа выдает ошибку.

Как можно обойти эту проблему?

Код

```
private void getQuestions()
    {

        // вытаскиваем все вопросы и ответы
        string[] qstns = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Resources\Questions.txt");
        string[] answrs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Resources\Answers.txt");

        int Q = qstns.Length;
        int A = answrs.Length;

        string msg = "";

        if (Q > 0 && A > 0)
        {
            if (Q == A)
            {
                QuestionAmount = qstns.Count();

                questions = new string[qstns.Count()];
                answers = new string[qstns.Count()];

                for (int i = 0; i < qstns.Length; i++)
                {
                    questions[i] = qstns[i];
                    answers[i] = answrs[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Ошибка! Кол-во ответов и вопросов, не совпадают.\nВ файле, в массиве у вас ответов: " + A.ToString() + " и вопросов: " + Q.ToString() + "\n\nВопросы отключенны!" + "\n\nДля добавления вопросов или ответов вы должны зайти в папку Resources рядом с игрой и отредактировать нужные файлы!";
                showErrorMsg = true;
            }
        }else{
            msg = "Вопросы или ответы не найдены! Вы играете без вопросов...";
            showErrorMsg = true;
        }

        if (showErrorMsg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "Ошибка ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            useQuestions = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно заключить попытку чтения из файлов в блок `try..catch`. Таким образом вы сможете поймать исключение и обработать его. Ниже примитивный пример

```
try
{
    string[] qstns = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Resources\Questions.txt");
    string[] answrs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Resources\Answers.txt");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // если сработал блок catch значит мы поймали исключение
    // выводим его в месседжбоксе для анализа
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Ошибка ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    useQuestions = false;
    // выходим из метода
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ну у меня сперва такая идея возникла и это скорей всего правильно получить перехваченную ошибку "FileNotFoundException", но я использовал File.Exist или как то так

Answer (score 4):

Не имеет смысла тестировать заранее, существует ли файл: его могут удалить сразу после того, как ваш тест отработал.

В случае отсутствия файла на момент открытия, [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) выбрасывает исключение `FileNotFoundException`. Просто ловите его и реагируйте разумным образом. Если может исчезнуть и каталог, ловите ещё и `DirectoryNotFoundException`. (Посмотрите в документацию, какие исключения бросаются в каких случаях.)

Answer (score 2):

Проверка на наличие файла

```
...
var msg = string.Empty;
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
if(!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    msg = string.Format("Файл: {0} не найден",fileName);
}
...
```

Comment: Неверно. Между проверкой и фактическим использованием файла файл может исчезнуть. Избежать try/catch невозможно.

Comment: @VladD а try/catch и не надо избегать, однако лучше в него сразу и не впадать

Comment: Это да, но в данном случае проверка `fileInfo.Exists` не спасает от необходимости в try/catch. Хотя конечно при возможности обойти try/catch надо обходить.